# Excel macro to remove rows without special character and remove special characters from another rows

Tags: excel, vba

I've encountered a small problem, that even internet can't help me fix (or I'm just too stupid ;)).

So the thing is that I've got few huge Excel files with users login names in row A, but the data is completely corrupted - there should be only login name instead of whole e-mail, ex:

```
login1

login2

login3@provider.com

login4@provider.com

login5
... etc.
```

My problem is that I was asked to create a list of login names only for people that entered them with a whole e-mail address. So the thing is that I can do it manually, but it will take a lot of time... is there a way in Excel to do it automatically? Sth. like: if cell A1 doen't have '@' - remove row / if it has '@' delete everything starting with '@'?

I would appreciate any help - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Excel Filters to filter all values without @ and delete rows then. Then use this formula in cell B1 if email address is in cell A1.

```
=LEFT(A1;FIND("@";A1)-1)
```

The above formula will return all the characters before @

NOTE: You might have the replace semi-colon(;) with comma(,) in your formula